# Python 2.7.1 - Pynomo - alignment of scales in circular type 8 nomograms

Tags: python

first question from my side. For the last couple of month self-teaching I have figured out everything using stack overflow and clumsy own designs, but now I am stuck since days:
I use Pynomo to make nomograms with some very fine results. My newest project is to design a circular nomogram using multiple "type 8" conversion charts like in 
http://www.myreckonings.com/pynomo/CreatingNomogramsWithPynomo.pdf
starting from page 30.
However I cannot properly line up, or influence how to line up, the circular charts. In the example given the charts mostly shared a common minimum (zero). My functions however (all like AxB+C) do not share a common minimum. I easily manage to distribute the values for each scale in a circle but the circles do not line up at their minima.

Does anyone have an idea or a workaround how I can line up the minimum of scale "32 to 340" with "66 to 285" (for example) so 32 and 66 correspond?

I could provide some example code but I guess the problem is very specific to Pynomo and regular users will know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

to whom it might concern: I figured out a solution. It is clumsy alright, but I am neither a programmer nor mathematician.

I was trying to show 3 different items in one graph as "pie pieces", 110 degrees each, with some space in between (think mercedes benz sign). For each piece a number of circle fragments with scales was to be displayed with a result scale on the outside. 
So for item 1, you find find the group you are interested in (circle fragment), draw from bullsey through it to the outer ring and read a result. If you want, repeat for items 2 and 3.

Since all fragments and pieces followed the general formula:

Result = (Measurement x A) + B

I was running into the problem that the circle fragments appeared rotated against each other with one starting at 10 degrees, the other at 113 and so on.
To set each fragment to the correct beginning, therefore forming a nice cake piece, I had to do the following:
determine the dimensions of your cake piece (i chose 110 degrees).
determine your result range, you are interested in (i was only interested in results from 1.5 to 2.0).
calculate for each group in a cake piece the minimum and maximum measurement for the minimum and maximum results.
Subtract the minimum from maximum and divide by the cake piece dimensions (/110 in my case) to give you "units per degree".
Now decide on the starting position of the cake piece (zero is usually "east" position) and calculate the relative degrees to your minimum measurement value as "starting point", for example 45 degrees.
Multiply that number of degrees with the "units per degree". Now you have everything to construct the nomograph pieces. You do not have to fill it in completely, checking your assumptions by applying the numbers to the outer or inner most part should give you a good estimate where everything ends up in the full nomograph.
In my case (one block only):

Center2_params={
    'u_min':25.2413,
    'u_max':42.4827,

'function_x':lambda u:9*math.cos((math.radians(110/(42.4827-25.2413))*(u+10.025078))),#*2*pi/360*56.4),

'function_y':lambda u:9*math.sin((math.radians(110/(42.4827-25.2413))*(u+10.025078))),#*2*pi/360*56.4),

```
'title':r'your title here',
'tick_levels':4,
'tick_text_levels':2,
'tick_side':'right', 
'axis_color':color.gray(0.10),
'text_color':color.gray(0.10),
'title_color':color.gray(0.10),
}
```

Center2_block_params={
    'block_type':'type_8',
    'f_params':Center2_params,
    'width':15.0,
    'height':15.0,
    }

Read up on circle coordinates if needed.
As in the pdf example, I included a bullseye center. I could have displayed all pieces in one nomogram but instead created 3 single nomograms and imported them from pdf into GIMP where I combined them (select by color - click white- pick "selection - invert", copy and paste as new layer.
If you go this route make sure to uncommen the "scale paper" option:
'transformations':[('rotate',0.01)],#('scale paper',)],
Since this option tries to optimally use all the paper, producing curvy nomograms from the pie piece. This looks cool and more sophisticated, but makes combining 3 Nomograms a pain. By uncommenting you get nice pieces. Overlay them bullseye in GIMP, if necessary rotate the pieces with the rotate tool. Make sure to move the pivot point on the bullseye.
Hope this helps anybody.

PS: note that in this nomogram style, all scales are independent (basically overlayed with ticks pointing to left and right), so nothing "automatically follows)